# Text seems out of place next to logo

Tags: website-design, logo, text, critique

I'm not a designer in any way, but I'm having to design an app/web site for a customer and I'd like to know if the text here seems 'boring' next to the logo: it seems out of place and left there without thoughts (same about the smaller leaves).

I've already tried wrapping the text around the lower part of the leaf but it just wasn't natural (plus I didn't found a font that looked good that way). I like the outcome but there's something weird about it and I just can't figure out how to make it look less sketchy.[image: company's logo: red leave to the left beside the company's name, with two smaller leaves of same format in the background]

Comment: I suggest you look at your logo at the size you plan to use it, which is probably 4-5x smaller. You might already get a lot of your questions answered just by doing this. Maybe you could post a few more examples of what you've tried too. I can't help but wonder why you're doing a logo if you aren't a designer. Not that easy, eh?  :)

Comment: @go-meek yep, budget reasons ;) you guys rock, i'm just trying to make something that doesn't come out that terrible haha, and thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I would stay away from putting design elements behind any of your text. It's a bit distracting, but also, but depending on how you print it, it could cause some legibility issues with your text if they come out too dark. You could ditch the two little leaves, make the big brown one a little smaller (so it's not completely dwarfing your text), and consider making that leaf green. Healthy plants seem like a good thing to promote with a landscaping business. Just my 2 cents. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I like the leaves, they don't bother me much even if they're behind the text but I find the text too small. That's why I suggested you look at it at small size too. If you use that logo on apps or website, the attention is drawn to the red leaves and less on the name. It needs a bit more impact!

[image: 120px logo sample]

For example, using a bolder font, condensed or normal, by playing with the uppercase and sizes. You can also move the leaves to the side or on top, change their colors or match a part of the text with some of the leaves' colors.

I made some samples using the *Interstate font* but it could be any other font that is easy to read. You can even mix script and sans serif if you want to add even more emphasis on some of the words; for example, maybe your client wants the word "naturally" to be the main focus or "landscaping".

The leaves are interesting because you can place them in a way to add some movement to your logo, as if they were flying in the wind.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would firstly remove the leaves from behind the text, then shrink the leaf to the same height as the text.

Comment: Hi revrev, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where this entire block (logo + text) is to be used. As you said you're planning to use it in an app/website, I presume it should be somewhere in the header. My suggestion to you would be:

- Change the color of the main logo (if possible) to something more
  reddish (ex: #cc0033) to make it more vibrant.
- Remove the background falling leaves as it seems to create distraction.
- Experiment a bit by changing the font to something like Oswald.
- Use a contrasting font color (bluish shade, maybe).